# How to terminate windows sockets when internet is down? (C++ WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock, winsock2

I have set up a Winsock2 connection but I need to cover the case where internet is down. Here is my code;

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    WSADATA w;
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&w)) return 0;
    sockaddr_in sad;
    sad.sin_family=AF_INET;
    sad.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("200.20.186.76");
    sad.sin_port=htons(123);
    sockaddr saddr;
    int saddr_l=sizeof(saddr);
    int s=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);
    if(s==INVALID_SOCKET) return 0;
    char msg[48]={8};
    if(sendto(s,msg,sizeof(msg),0,(sockaddr*)&sad,sizeof(sad))==SOCKET_ERROR) return 0;
    if(recvfrom(s,msg,48,0,&saddr,&saddr_l)==SOCKET_ERROR) return 0;
    if(closesocket(s)==SOCKET_ERROR) return 0;
    if(WSACleanup()) return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Here it waits for the call to return as it's documented. I have two questions.

1. Can I set a timeout like we can do when using `select`
2. How else can I prevent the waiting and make it return immediately? Documentation states that:

> When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as sendto, Winsock may need to wait for a network event before the call can complete. Winsock performs an alertable wait in this situation, which can be interrupted by an asynchronous procedure call (APC) scheduled on the same thread.

How to do that?

Comment: AFAIK you can't detect connection loss from the socket with UDP due to it is connectionless. You need to use some workaround on this.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon Right, thank you. I'll try pinging somewhere first or think about something else.

Comment: Use a read timeout, with `setsockopt()` and `SO_RCVTIMEO`.

Comment: @user207421 I've already looked at those document pages but they require connection-oriented protocols like TCP. I'm using UDP and it's connectionless so these methods possibly won't work.

Comment: "*Can I set a timeout like we can do when using `select`*" - You can use `select()` with a UDP socket. And FYI, `SO_RCVTIMEO` works with UDP, as well.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Ah, thank you. I'll try it during the day.

Comment: SO_RCVTIMEO does not 'require connection-oriented protocols like TCP'. Cannot imagine where you got that idea from.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to issue a recvfrom() and have it return immediately, then decide on your own how long to wait (I'm assuming Windows since you included winsock2.h), you can make an asynchronous OVERLAPPED request, then wait for the completion at any time by waiting for the hEvent member of the OVERLAPPED struct to be signaled.

Here's an updated sample based off your original code.

- you set the timeout by waiting as long as you need with WaitForSingleObject (below I wait for 10 seconds 6 times)
- by passing an OVERLAPPED pointer, you are indicating that you will wait for the completion yourself. Note that the OVERLAPPED struct cannot go out of scope until the hEvent is signaled. (or freed, if the OVERLAPPED was dynamically allocated).
- Letting the OVERLAPPED go out of scope before guaranteeing the IO completed is a common Winsock bug (I've been working on Winsock for over 10 years or so - I've seen many variations of this bug)
- As commented below, if you don't know hEvent has been signaled, then after calling closesocket you *must* wait for hEvent to be signaled before continuing - closesocket does not guarantee all asynchronous IO request have completed before returning.

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    WSADATA w;
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &w)) return 0;
    sockaddr_in sad;
    sad.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sad.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("200.20.186.76");
    sad.sin_port = htons(123);
    sockaddr saddr;
    int saddr_l = sizeof(saddr);
    int s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET) return 0;
    char msg[48] = { 8 };
    if (sendto(s, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, (sockaddr*)&sad, sizeof(sad)) == SOCKET_ERROR) return 0;
    OVERLAPPED ov{};
    ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(nullptr, TRUE, FALSE, nullptr);
    if (ov.hEvent == nullptr) return 0;
    WSABUF wsabuffer{};
    wsabuffer.buf = msg;
    wsabuffer.len = 48;
    DWORD flags = 0;
    if (WSARecvFrom(s, &wsabuffer, 1, nullptr, &flags, &saddr, &saddr_l, &ov, nullptr) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        DWORD gle = WSAGetLastError();
        if (gle != WSA_IO_PENDING) return 0;
    }
    for (DWORD recv_count = 0; recv_count < 6; ++recv_count)
    {
        DWORD wait = WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, 10000);
        if (wait == WAIT_FAILED) return 0;
        if (wait == WAIT_OBJECT_0) break; // WSARecvFrom completed
        if (wait == WAIT_TIMEOUT) continue; // WSARecvFrom is still pended waiting for data
    }
    // assuming WSARecvFrom completed - i.e. ov.hEvent was signaled
    DWORD transferred;
    if (WSAGetOverlappedResult(s, &ov, &transferred, FALSE, &flags))
    {
        // WSARecvFrom completed successfully - 'transferred' shows the # of bytes that were received
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD gle = WSAGetLastError();
        gle;
        // WSARecvFrom failed with the error code in 'gle'
    }
    if (closesocket(s) == SOCKET_ERROR) return 0;
    // with real code, we must guarantee that hEvent is set after calling closesocket
    // e.g. if we get here in an error path
    // closesocket() won't guarantee all async IO has completed before returning
    WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, INFINITE);
    if (WSACleanup()) return 0;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm trying this now. By the way, I have a question, what happens if we don't wait for the _hEvent_ at the end of the program? Does it cause undefined behaviour, memory leak or crash? If it doesn't cause such problems, why does it matter?

Comment: There is no need to wait on the Event a 2nd time in this example, since the 1st wait already guaranteed the Event is set. And calling `WaitForSingleObject()` in a loop in this manner is completely unnecessary when a single call with the total timeout will accomplish the exact same thing. However, this code is a bit overkill when `select()` and `SO_RCVTIMEO` can accomplish the exact same thing with much less code. This is not the best use of Overlapped I/O.

Comment: This is taking a hammer to crack a nut. A `SO_RCVTIMEO` nut.

Comment: As mentioned, if you have guaranteed that the IO has completed (hEvent was already signaled), then you don't  need to wait a second time. If the code timed out, then you must wait after calling closesocket(). If you don't wait, then at some random / undefined time in the future, Winsock (from kernel) will update that OVERLAPPED struct - potentially corrupting the stack.

You can also use select to know when to post recvfrom. But I personally favor OVERLAPPED IO - I don't see the code is much more complicated and gives you many more options if you need to wait for other signals to exit.

Comment: (Note: I called this in a loop just to give an example of how one can call this repeatedly if necessary - this is all just example code. If there was just a single time to wait, then of course it wouldn't be called in a loop).